Print Error After Some Prints Thermal Printing
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new();
        printDialog.Document = printDocumentCustomer;
        printDocumentCustomer.Print();

        printDialog = new();
        printDialog.Document = printDocumentMerchant;
        printDocumentMerchant.Print();
    }

    private void DrawGraphics(PrintPageEventArgs e, string copyOf){
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Font font = new("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Bold);

    StringFormat center = new(StringFormatFlags.FitBlackBox);
    center.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    int y = 0;
    g.DrawString($"** {Task.Run(async () => await CommonData.GetById<LocationModel>("LocationTable", locationId)).Result.FirstOrDefault().Name} **", new Font("Courier New", 20, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 25, y += 10);
    g.DrawString($"----- {copyOf} Copy -----", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 40);
    g.DrawString($"Slip No.: {slipId}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 25);
    g.DrawString($"DT: {transaction.DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm")}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 25);
    g.DrawString($"Name: {Task.Run(async () => await PersonData.GetPersonByNumber(numberTextBox.Text)).Result.FirstOrDefault().Name}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    g.DrawString($"Contact: {numberTextBox.Text}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    if (loyaltyCheckBox.Checked) g.DrawString("Loyalty Member", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    g.DrawString($"Reservation: {Task.Run(async () => await CommonData.GetById<ReservationTypeModel>("ReservationTypeTable", transaction.ReservationType)).Result.FirstOrDefault().Name}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);

    g.DrawString("--------------------------", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    g.DrawString($"Total Persons: {transaction.Male + transaction.Female}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    g.DrawString("Male\tFemale", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    g.DrawString($"{transaction.Male}\t{transaction.Female}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);

    g.DrawString("--------------------------", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    g.DrawString($"Total: {transaction.Cash + transaction.Card + transaction.UPI + transaction.Amex}", new("Courier New", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    g.DrawString($"{MakeStringHeaderAmount(transaction)}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    g.DrawString($"{MakeStringAmount(transaction)}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);

    g.DrawString("--------------------------", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    if (transaction.ApprovedBy != null) g.DrawString($"Approved By: {transaction.ApprovedBy}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);
    g.DrawString($"Entered By: {Task.Run(async () => await CommonData.GetById<EmployeeModel>("EmployeeTable", transaction.EmployeeId)).Result.FirstOrDefault().Name}", font, Brushes.Black, 10, y += 20);

    g.DrawString("This coupon is non-transferable", new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 8, y += 30);
    g.DrawString("to any person or any other outlet.", new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 8, y += 10);
    g.DrawString("This coupon is to be redeemed", new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 8, y += 10);
    g.DrawString("until the end of the operations", new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 8, y += 10);
    g.DrawString("of the particular night:", new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 8, y += 10);
    g.DrawString($"{transaction.DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm")}", new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 8, y += 10);
    g.DrawString("The hotel does not take liability", new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 8, y += 10);
    g.DrawString("or responsibility if the coupon", new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 8, y += 10);
    g.DrawString("is lost by the guest", new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 8, y += 10);

    PaperSize ps58 = new("58mm Thermal", 220, y += 20);
    printDocumentCustomer.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps58;

    e.HasMorePages = false;}

    private void printDocumentCustomer_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawGraphics(e, "Customer");
    }

    private void printDocumentMerchant_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawGraphics(e, "Merchant");
    }

This Code Prints the contents in a thermal printer but it cuts the right side of the print after some prints. The error only comes in one of the copies. What can possible solutions and why is it happening. Does Restarting the Print Spooler after ever save ? Help ?
Print Copies
